# Cups and caps inequality: $f(s,t) \leq {s+t-2 \choose {s-2}}+1$

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, discrete-geometry, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

A sequence of consecutive line segments in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is called a **Cap** if their slopes are monotonically decreasing, and a **Cup** if their slopes are monotonically increasing. Let $f(s,t)$ denote the smallest number for which any collection of $f(s,t)$ points in general position either contains a **Cap** of length $s$ or a **Cup** of length $t$.

I already proved that $f(s,t) \leq f(s−1,t) + f(s,t−1) + 1 \text{ for all } s,t \geq 4$ $(*)$.

To prove the inequality in the title, I tried induction on $(s+t)$, applying it to $f(s−1,t) \text{ and } f(s,t−1)$ in $(*)$. Yet all I got is $f(s,t) \leq {s+t-2 \choose {s-2}} + 3$ and can't find any way to reduce the last term to $1$. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I misread at first your definition. Now, something puzzles me : when you say "consecutive line segments", you do not place any condition on **abscissas** of endpoints like being  consecutive integers for example (or, equivalently, being an arithmetical sequence) ? What do you mean by "any set of points in general position" ?  how are numbered your points ? By increasing abscissas ? You should provide an example...

Comment: Could you answer me ?

Comment: These are the examples that come with the problem: https://imgur.com/hvvJvO7. I guess the points are indeed ordered by increasing x-coordinates. Also the points being in general position means that no triples are on a same line.